# Dune: build library and access it in another project and hide or make inaccessible private or implementation modules

Tags: ocaml, opam, ocaml-dune

I am using [Dune](https://dune.build/) for building OCaml projects and I'd like to build a standalone library for reusing it in other projects.

The root folder of the library is `mylib` and the library was initialized with `dune init lib mylib src` (after `cd mylib`).

The directory tree of `mylib`, the root of the project, is the following:

```
mylib
+---dune-project
│
+---src
        dune
        priv.ml
        mymodule.ml
        mymodule.mli
```

Here follows the content of the files.

**mylib/dune-project**:

```
(lang dune 2.7)
```

**mylib/src/dune**:

```
(library
 (name mylib))
```

**mylib/src/priv.ml**:

```
let rec loop a accu i =
  let n = Array.length a in
  if i = n then
    accu
  else
    loop a (accu + Array.unsafe_get a i) (succ i)
```

**mylib/src/mymodule.mli**:

```
val sum : int array -> int
```

**mylib/src/mymodule.ml**:

```
let sum a =
  Priv.loop a 0 0
```

After giving context and showing the content of each file of this toy example, the question follows:

1. How can I build the library `mylib` and use it in another, separate project?

(For example, in another project, I'd consume the library with the following:

```
Open Mylib
let () =
  print_int (Mymodule.sum [1;2;3])
```

OR

```
let () =
  print_int (Mylib.Mymodule.sum [1;2;3])
```

)

With Dune, given the executable `main`, you would write the following `dune` file to use library `mylib` if it was published on [Opam](https://opam.ocaml.org/).

**dune**:

```
(executable
 (name main)
 (libraries mylib))
```

2. After successfully building the library and linking it in another project, how can I hide or not expose some modules? For example, given the toy library of before, `mylib`, I would like to not expose and make inaccessible the module `Priv` (such that `Priv` would only be usable inside modules of `mylib` - like a protected/internal class in Java/C#).

​

I tried searching on [Real World OCaml](https://dev.realworldocaml.org/), [Cornell CS3110 textbook](https://www.cs.cornell.edu/courses/cs3110/2021sp/textbook/intro/intro.html), [Dune documentation](https://dune.readthedocs.io/en/stable/), [OCaml Learn](https://ocaml.org/learn/) but, unless deeply nested, I found nothing.

Thank you very much for your help, if I didn't explain something in a clear way, please ask and I will try to explain better.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

1. In the root directory, these should be a file called `mylib.opam` with content similar to [this one](https://opam.ocaml.org/doc/Packaging.html). Then, the `(public_name mylib)` s-expression should be added to `library` in **mylib/src/dune**. Finally, making sure to be in the root of the project, the library shall be built with `dune build` and installed with `opam install .`.
   For actually using the library in another project, even in a different dune workspace, all it's needed is to add `(libraries mylib)` to the dune file of project that will use the library.
2. The `(private_modules priv)` s-expression should be added to `library` in **mylib/src/dune**. Then, `mylib.ml` needs to be created with the following content: `module Mymodule = Mymodule`: this will make sure that only `Mymodule` will be exposed under the package `Mylib`.